# Special characters handling in OSB 11g

Tags: osb

How to handle the special characters in OSB 11g.
I am getting special characters from Mainframe and wherein the jave application placed into Queue and hence I consumed the Request from queue and process to further action .But I got the special characters so how I can handle into OSB 11g.

I am happy any one can help us.

Thanks,

Comment: What are 'special characters'?  Are you referring to UTF-8 encoded strings?  What does the request look like coming in?  Is the Queue using a TextMessage or some binary-encoded one?  Are you trying to use escape characters in a message and you think it's interpreting those?

Having more information is better, and in this case, you're not really saying anything.  Stack Overflow isn't great for conversations, so you need to put it all out there if you hope to have someone answer it.

Answer (score 0):

OSB implements UTF-8 by defult which take cares almost all special characters. If you dont want your message to be parsed then better use CDATA. Here assuming that message is XML document as not mentioned in question.